# Select statement with unique format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a table with a column 'Number' which contain values like INV-00100,INV-00101,INV-00102,INV-00103 etc.

I want to get highest value +1  in a format like "INV-00103". How it possible?
Any suggestions??

I have tried this query

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(Number, 5, LEN(Number) - 4) AS INT)), 0) AS [MaxNo] 
FROM 
    Table
```

But this statement returns like "103" as result. I want to get this "103" as "00103" (total of 5 digits).

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? As it stands this sounds quite trivial. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like follwoing.

```
 DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(Code VARCHAR(100))
 INSERT INTO @TABLE
 VALUES ('INV-00100'),('INV-00101'),('INV-00102') 

 SELECT RIGHT('00000'+ 
  CAST(MAX(TRY_PARSE(SUBSTRING(Code,CHARINDEX('-',Code)+1,
  LEN(Code)-CHARINDEX('-',Code)) AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10)),5)
 FROM @TABLE
```

**Output**

```
00103
```

**Edit:**

> This is working fine.. But what will happen if the Number exceeds
>   99999?? Will this give a value like INV-100000 – Vahid

```
 DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(Code VARCHAR(100))
 INSERT INTO @TABLE
 VALUES ('INV-00100'),('INV-00101'),('INV-00102') 

 SELECT 
 (
 CASE WHEN  [Output] > 99999 THEN CAST([Output] AS VARCHAR(100))
  --MORE CONDITION
  ELSE RIGHT('00000'+CAST([Output] AS VARCHAR(100)),5)
  END
 ) AS [Output]

  FROM
 (
 SELECT 
  MAX(TRY_PARSE(SUBSTRING(Code,CHARINDEX('-',Code)+1,
  LEN(Code)-CHARINDEX('-',Code)) AS INT) + 1) AS [Output]
 FROM @TABLE
 ) T
```

Comment: This is working fine.. But what will happen if the Number exceeds 99999??
Will this give a value like INV-100000

Comment: you can put case condition like value > 100000 then pick a particular format.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
select left('INV-00100',6) + cast(max(cast(right('INV-00100', 5) as int) + 1)as VARCHAR)
```